# How come Drupal Console is not downloading all commands?

Tags: 8, composer, console

When adding Drupal Console using Composer, we are finding that the list of commands is not complete. How can I resolve the issue?

#### Installation steps:

1. change to root directory (`/local/path/drupal-site`)
2. run `composer require drupal/console:~1.0 --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader`
3. run `composer update drupal/console --with-dependencies`

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Change to either Change to `drupal-site/vendor/bin/` or `drupal-site/vendor/drupal/console/bin` directory
2. run `drupal generate:form`
3. error message below is returned.
4. change to root directory (`/local/path/drupal-site`)
5. run `vendor/bin/drupal generate:form`
6. error message below is returned again.

> [ERROR] Command "generate:form", is not a valid command name.

Versions:

1. Drupal core v8.5.5
2. Composer 1.6.3
3. Drupal console 1.8.0

#### output of `drupal list`

[image: drupal list]

Comment: You’re probably running it outside a bootstrapped Drupal - the list of available commands is substantially shorter when you do that

Comment: @Clive how would we install it otherwise? The Drupal site was installed using Composer.

Comment: You need to run the command inside the web folder, otherwise drupal console doesn't find the drupal installation

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours on chasing this same issue, i quit and now use drush to create boilerplate stuff such as module, plugins etc.
After you install drupal site via composer with --dev try the following.

```
./vendor/drush/drush/drush generate module-standard # other generate commands there as well
```

Comment: Yes, Drush has generators now.